# Caching Expensive Results

Tags: apex

I'm building a custom interface in Visualforce that uses dependent picklists.  Since Apex doesn't expose information about dependent picklist values, I've had to resort to [building that information on the client side and sending it up to my controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/get-lists-of-dependent-picklist-options-in-apex/4876#4876).  The problem is that's expensive processing to do on every page load when the picklist options themselves will change very frequently.  **As such, is there a way to store/cache the information in SFDC so that I can update it only when it changes?**

**Approaches I've tried and ruled out:**

1. **Custom Settings:** this seemed like the obvious choice, but a JSON representation of my picklist data is significantly longer than the maximum field length.
2. **Static Resources:** it's not possible to create Static Resources from Apex, so I'd have to manually update the resource when there are changes -- it wouldn't be possible to build a VF page to do this for me.

Comment: You can set the Cache attribute to true in page so that page is cached .http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/cache-visualforce-pages-on-forcecom-sites.Refer this site for more info

Comment: Custom settings is a good choice .You need not fill in JSON.Platform will automatically convert into JSON.Paste your JSON i will help you how to generate same from custom settings

Comment: We need not store JSON in custom settings .JSON can be easily generated through apex rest .

Answer (score 7):

Benj, since you're using the JavaScript Ajax Toolkit to get at the Dependent Picklist API, another option is to cache the information using JavaScript as well, by storing it in **HTML5 Local / Session Storage**, with a fallback either to Cookies or Custom Settings (as per Andrew Fawcett's 'striping' approach, which is a good solution as well) for older browsers that do not support HTML5. We've used this for caching calls to `describeTabs`, and it's worked great. HTML5 Session/Local storage is definitely the way to go looking forward, as it's lightning fast, gives you plenty of storage space, and is all client-side, so after the first call there's no work at all done in Apex.

Here's a great [intro to HTML5 Local/Session Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Here's the basic approach you'd need to do in Visualforce/JavaScript to get this going:

1. Create some storage getter/setter methods that will do the hard work of checking for support of local/session storage and falling back to cookies if necessary.
2. On page load, check your storage for a cached picklist dependencies key in your storage.
3. If the cache exists, grab it! Otherwise, do a call to AJAX API to retrieve the info you need. Then, strip the info down to the bare minimum you need to store (the AJAX API calls often return a lot of needless bloat, I recommend parsing your responses down to just what you need), and then use `JSON.stringify()` to convert your data to JSON before storing it in your cache.

**Part 1: Create your Local Storage Repo**

```
// The canUseLocalStorage() function will let you know
// if HTML5 local storage is supported
var _canUseLocalStorage = 'nodata',
canUseLocalStorage = function(){
    if (_canUseLocalStorage === 'nodata') {
        try {
          return (_canUseLocalStorage = 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null);
        } catch (e) {
          return (_canUseLocalStorage = false);
        }
    } else return _canUseLocalStorage;
},
// Store stuff in local storage, if possible,
// otherwise fall back to cookies
localStorage = function(key,value) {
    // Can we use storage?
    var canUseStorage = canUseLocalStorage();
    return (
        // If we're RETRIEVING content...
        (typeof value === 'undefined') ? (
            // Use Local Storage
            (canUseStorage) ? window.localStorage[key] 
            // Use cookies
            : $.cookie(key,value)
        )
        // If we're STORING content
        : (
            // Use Session Storage
            (canUseStorage) ? (window.localStorage[key] = value) 
            // Use cookies
            : $.cookie(key,value)
        )
    );
};
```

**Part 2: Check to see if your storage repo has a cached result**

```
// Our key(s) will be called 'picklistCache_<objectName>_<fieldName>`
// So here's an example for the Account Type field
var cacheName = 'picklistCache_Account_AccountType',
    cacheResult = localStorage(cacheName);

// If we did NOT have such a result, 
// we'll need to query the AJAX API
if (!cacheResult) {
    if (sforce.connection.sessionId) {
        // Query the AJAX API for the Picklist Dependency info,
        // using the strategy in the following article:
        // http://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/dependent-picklists-in-salesforce-without-metadata-api-or-visualforce/

        // ....
        // ANd stringify your result once you're done!
        cacheResult = JSON.stringify(cacheResult);

        // Once we've got our data, cache it!
        localStorage(cacheName,cacheResult);

    }

}

// Now use the result to do your client-side picklist dependency work!
if (cacheResult) {
     // Unpack our JSON result
     cacheResult = JSON.parse(cacheResult);

    // Render dependent picklists
}
```

Comment: Excellent idea to take advantage of HTML 5's local storage.

Comment: Seems like this may be the best option, but even that seems like a heavier lift.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Settings are ideal for this.

- You can either create a [List based](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/cs_about.htm) Custom Setting and split your information accross multiple rows.
- Or span your information accross multiple fields, if you have reasonable confidence on the maximum size. I used this second approach recently to store Ebay's API ID which is quite large but finite.

Either way the following should hopefully help you...

```
    // Custom setting fields have a max of 255, so we need to split this api token up
    eBayAPI__c ebayAPI = eBayAPI__c.getInstance();
    List<String> chunks = splitIntoChunks(EbayAPIToken, 255);
    ebayAPI.UserTokenPart1__c = null;
    ebayAPI.UserTokenPart2__c = null;
    ebayAPI.UserTokenPart3__c = null;
    ebayAPI.UserTokenPart4__c = null;   
    if(chunks.size()>0)
        ebayAPI.UserTokenPart1__c = chunks[0];                  
    if(chunks.size()>1)
        ebayAPI.UserTokenPart2__c = chunks[1];                  
    if(chunks.size()>2)
        ebayAPI.UserTokenPart3__c = chunks[2];                  
    if(chunks.size()>3)
        ebayAPI.UserTokenPart4__c = chunks[3];                  
    upsert ebayAPI;
    return null;
```

This is the helper function I  used to split the string.

```
    private List<String> splitIntoChunks(String text, integer chunkSize)
    {
        // Util code to split up large strings
        List<String> chunks = new List<String>();
        integer offset = 0;
        while (offset < text.length())
        {
            integer partSize = Math.min(chunkSize, text.length() - offset);
            chunks.add(text.substring(offset, offset + partSize));
            offset += partSize;
        }
        return chunks;
    }
```

Comment: This approach would be tedious to configure for very large strings that need to be stored (e.g. a 5000 character string, very small considering the size of the JSON-serialized representation of the Picklist Dependencies object, would require 20 textarea fields at 255 chars/per field). However, you can have up to 300 fields on a Custom Setting (as per the [Limits docs](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits.htm&language=en_US)), so this is theoretically doable. The "chunkifier" function will be really ugly, though.

Comment: Yes I think if your needing that level, I would use List based Custom Settings personally. The chunkifier can then be taught (or just assume field / row sizes) about the boundaries of the data and split across the rows or equally the columns (using Dynamic Apex to populate the fields) either way.

Comment: Yes that's true using Dynamic Apex you could easily iterate from `1...<n>` over as many fields as needed on the CustomSetting record if they were named using a convention, e.g. `CustomSetting__c.Data<n>__c`. I've done something like this before for striping on textarea fields on regular SObjects, and it works fine. But I would still start by caching the data client-side before resorting to server-side.