# Can a Web Tab's url be get and set from Apex or the REST Api?

Tags: apex, rest-api, sobject, url, web-tab

I would like to modify the url of my Web Tab for each SF organization that my managed package is installed on. Is there a way to get and set the url of a Web Tab from Apex or the REST Api? Is there a SObject that stores the state of a Web Tab? If so, what is its name?

[This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/984/how-can-i-get-a-web-tabs-url-from-apex) is similar but no apex code to modify the url was given.

If you want to learn more about Web Tabs, [start by making one in your org](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_web_tabs.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: This "Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API" https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi appears to include CustomTab: I haven't tried it so can't comment further though.

Answer (score 2):

I am taking a guess here :

Based on this question you can access the metadata api from apex as below :

[Has anyone, ever, successfully invoked the Metadata API from within Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/has-anyone-ever-successfully-invoked-the-metadata-api-from-within-apex/2207#2207)

In your case you need to be looking at customtab from here :

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/

Combining both might do the trick ")

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
MetadataService.CustomObject CustomTab = new MetadataService.CustomTab();
CustomTab.URL = 'www.abc.com';
//not sure what else u might need to create a tab, required vals might be missing here.
MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results = 
    service.create(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { CustomTab});
```